# Rewind a kafka consumer group offset to a given timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

We want to expose an endpoint that enables rewinding a kafka consumer group offset to a supplied timestamp. I know this functionality is provided in `ConsumerSeekCallback.seekToTimestamp`.

My issue is trying to get access to `ConsumerSeekCallback` in the controller to make the seek call.

I had two approaches.

My first approach was to use KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry

In my endpoint/controller I would do something like the following

```
        registry.getAllListenerContainers().forEach(c -> {
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> c2 = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) c;
            c2.getContainers().forEach(kafkaMessageListenerContainer -> {
                kafkaMessageListenerContainer
```

I was hoping I would be able to access
`kafkaMessageListenerContainer.listenerConsumer.seekCallback.seekToTimestamp(...);`

Not so, listenerConsumer protected - probably for good reason.

My next approach was to expose a method called `getConsumerSeekCallbacks`. That way I could access this in my controller

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private String payload = null;


    @KafkaListener(id = "getting-started", topics = "getting-started")
    public void receive(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key, String obj,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long timestamp,
                        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", consumerRecord.toString());
        LOGGER.info("Received message timestamp: {}, date: {}", timestamp,
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());

    }

    public Map<TopicPartition, ConsumerSeekCallback> getConsumerSeekCallbacks() {
        return this.getSeekCallbacks();
    }

}
```

and simplified controller code:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;


    @PostMapping(path = "/admin/reset/{timestamp}")
    public void send(@PathVariable String timestamp) {

        Map<TopicPartition, ConsumerSeekAware.ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallbacks = kafkaConsumer.getConsumerSeekCallbacks();
        long offsetTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - 129000 * 1000;
        seekCallbacks.forEach((tp, callback) -> {
            callback.seekToTimestamp(tp.topic(), tp.partition(), offsetTimestamp);
        });
    }
}
```

This works, though not every time and not entirely sure of threadsafety with this approach. Plus it feels very hacky to me.

I'm sure there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct. Although I would have a `List<AbstractConsumerSeekAware>` autowired in your `Controller` instead. And just call their `seekToTimestamp(long time)`. It does that iteration internally for you.